# how to get the touching position of large image in android

Tags: android, imageview

I need to get the touching position of image in android. Let me explain in detail as i am having a image user can touch and do pinchzoom for image resizing. When user touch the certain position i need to show the details about the particular position of image in seperate position.

If the image is in the fixed size of screen size then no problem to find position  it should fized for all device. How it possible? can any please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OnTouchListener{
  @Override 
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent mv) {
    float x = mv.getRawX();
    float y = mv.getRawY();
    return true;
  }
```

This will give you the screen position of the touch. If you need to calculate the X/Y within the image which isn't the full size of the screen you can get the start X/Y coordinates of the image with

```
v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
float v_x = v.getTop();
float v_y = v.getLeft();
float real_x = x - v_x;
float real_y = y - v_y;
```